# how to change anonymous to login/regist with credential flutter firebase without sign in and sign out

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

i make an app that let the user to login anonymously. then when the user want to save their data, they should login/regist.

**for the example below, i login anonymously and i get the uid "yVjOUSAxkae4xDKl1XVeLKjHwfG2"**

[image]
[image]

then when to save the data, user will be ask to login/regist first, like the image below
[image]

i've tried like this link https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#linking-user-accounts
that i should use "linkWithCredential"
my code like below

```
Future<void> anonymousLogInEmail({
    required User user,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {    
      AuthCredential credential =
          EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password);

      await user.linkWithCredential(credential);
      print("HEHEHEHEHHEHEE");
      print(user);
      print(await user);
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
      print("HOHOHOHOHO");
      print(user);
      print(await user);
      await user.reload();
      print("HAHAHAHA");
      print(user);
      print(await user);

      Navigator.pop(context, await user);
    } catch (e) {
      user = await AuthServices.logInAnonymous();
      print(e.toString());
      snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: const Text('email or username wrong'),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**i already have an account "kezia@gmail.com"**
[image]

**when i try to login with "kezia@gmail.com", i get error**
**[firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.**

but **when i try to regist with new email "newaccount@gmail.com" which is not registered before**, **it can change the anonymous user to new account**, like the image below, the uid is like my anonymous uid, and it upgrade to an email login
[image]

**but even though in firebase it update to newaccount, in my app it doesn't change and still read the anonymous user with the same uid like the image below**
[image]

maybe there is a way to make anonymous can login with registered account / register new account? thankyou